# Boost asio socket on windows can't async_connect

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, boost-asio

Error when async_connect is called, is

```
uncaught exception of type N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_6system12system_errorEEEEE
- socket_select_interrupter: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced
```

Demangled:

> `uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > - socket_select_interrupter: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced`

Here is some relevant code:

```html
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> tTCPSocketPtr;

boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> ioService =  boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> (new boost::asio::io_service());

socketPtr = tTCPSocketPtr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*ioService));

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(this->ipAddress),  this->port);


// Set a deadline for the connect operation.
deadline->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

socketPtr->async_connect(endpoint,
        boost::bind(&AConnection::handle_connect,
        shared_from_this(), _1, endpoint)); //errors out here
```

I've googled and have not found anything useful.

How  I do fix this error?
thank you,
sb

Comment: it doesn't error out at `// errors out here` for the simple reason that asynchronous operations don't execute inline. So you probably meant that if you stop before that point (or comment it out) you don't get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing nearly enough code.

Using my crystal ball, though,  I can guess your are getting Win32 error code, which could mean you're using invalid handles.

Seeing that you use `enable_shared_from_this`, I can guess that this contributes to your problem (although it's in code not shown).

My best guess is that you might be using `shared_from_this` from inside the constructor (which leads to error).

Comment: thank you sehe. the call to async_connect is not within a constructor. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, an async connect would end up being a call to [ConnectEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which isn't supported on operating systems earlier than Windows Vista.

So the most important question, IMHO, is what operating system are you attempting to run the code on?

Given you're running on an operating system that is supported by ConnectEx, the next check is that you don't have any LSPs installed that may be preventing ConnectEx being used. (Possibly the easiest way to check for this is to simply run the code on a clean install VM of the operating system in question)...

Comment: thanks Len, I'm working on your VM clean install idea